# Apache Ignite: Eviction policy not enabled with ONHEAP_TIERED error

Tags: java, ignite

In Apache Ignite,

Eviction policy not enabled with ONHEAP_TIERED mode for cache (entries will not be moved to off-heap store)

I got this error
What causes this error and how can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning and not an error.
This means you are limited with JVM Heap size and data will never moved to off-heap until you specified EvictionPolicy in CacheConfiguration.

Comment: What causes this warning?
Did I do something wrong with ignite configuration?

Comment: Try set this https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setEvictionPolicy-org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.EvictionPolicy-